# rga can't authenticate, rga.open fails

Tags: r, google-analytics-api

I'm having a very frustrating situation:

I'm trying to use R and Shiny to build a custom dashboard for data collected by Google Analytics. I'm using the [rga library](https://github.com/skardhamar/rga)  to connect to Google Analytics.

Every time I try to connect to Google Analytics I get the following error:

```
rga.open(instance = "ga")
Error in if (.self$tokenExpiresIn() <= 0) { : argument is of length zero
```

I cleared the RStudio session, the Browser cache, generated new app secrets and tried to use the other options to open a connection to GA mentioned at rga's Github README, but it's still not working.

Do you guys know what's the problem with my approach?

Comment: You can report this issue to the `rga` package creator [here](https://github.com/skardhamar/rga/issues)

Comment: Have you tried the example in the [R documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RGA/RGA.pdf) ? And I can't see there any `rga.open` function too.

Comment: @clemlaflemme: Thanks, yes I did. I tried the authorize() function to check wheter my credentials are wrong. But R says: "could not find function authorize" with library rga loaded.

Comment: GitHub version is old (see date of submission of CRAN package RGA agains GitHub dates). Try removing things you've installed and run `install.packages("RGA")` to get a stable working version

Comment: Thank you very much, now it works. Seems like the CRAN version is the one you should stick to!